# Adding in SQL Column that Totals Other Column Values

Tags: mysql

Trying to add a new column into pre-existing table with the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE randomquestions 
ADD Total AS R1_Number + R2_Number + R3_Number + R4_Number PERSISTED
```

I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS R1_Number + R2_Number + R3_Number + R4_Number PERSISTED' at line 2

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Please provide error message and `DDL` of your table

Comment: Please decide `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server` **Microsoft SQL Server** or **MySQL**.

Comment: You're saying you get an error telling you to read MySQL documentation in SQL Server?

Comment: I think you must provide datatype after column name.

Answer (score 1):

If `MySQL 5.7.6+` [Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

```
ALTER TABLE randomquestions 
ADD Total INT AS (R1_Number + R2_Number + R3_Number + R4_Number) STORED;
```

Note that you may need to change datatype depending of datatype of `Rx_Number`.

Comment: But error message says otherwise ?,please update question

Answer (score 0):

Alter looks good missing parenthesis and column type.

```
ALTER TABLE randomquestions 
ADD Total int AS (R1_Number + R2_Number + R3_Number + R4_Number) PERSISTED
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar statement with the parenthesis and it worked:

```
use test
alter table [dbo].[tablename]
Add total2 as (price * 2) persisted
```

(so I guess it's the parenthesis, it's not finding your table, or just a syntax error with the field names.)